# docker unable to use secrets inside docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I'm trying to use docker secrets to store an external api key which is used on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, although it appears I'm missing something? Here is my current configuration with screenshots and api key blurred out:

[with_secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqiQO.jpg)

[without_secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4dIN.jpg)

docker-compose.yml with secret:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    image: "s_censored_p:latest"
    environment:
      bestbuy.api.url: /run/secrets/api_key
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    secrets:
      - api_key

secrets:
  api_key:
    external: true
```

docker-compose.yml without secret:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    image: "s_censored_p:latest"
    environment:
      bestbuy.api.url: "https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(sku in(6462266))?pageSize=100&cursorMark=*&format=csv&apiKey=qU_censored_CJ"
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
```

docker terminal details

```
➜  ~ docker secret ls
ID                          NAME      DRIVER    CREATED       UPDATED
pp8vsbxqk9z85zmdlnaxrudsl   api_key             2 hours ago   2 hours ago
➜  ~
➜  ~ docker service ls
ID             NAME      MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                        PORTS
gen8g85of3b2   api_key   replicated   1/1        s_censored_p:latest
➜  ~
➜  ~ docker exec -it $(docker ps --filter name=api_key -q) cat /run/secrets/api_key
https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(sku in(6462266))?pageSize=100&cursorMark=*&format=csv&apiKey=qU_censored_CJ%
➜  ~
➜  ~
```

Comment: screenshots do not count as details for a stack overflow post.  Please include text based data and supporting information

Comment: Sorry, I have just updated the post with text details, please let me know if you spot any errors I can't seem to figure out why docker secrets is not working.

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?  What's the content of the image?  The `docker-compose.yml` on its own superficially looks fine but without an [mcve] or a clear error description it's hard to give more advice.

Comment: The problem I am encountering is that the environment variable "bestbuy.api.url" inside docker-compose.yml only works if pasted in "plain-text". I created a docker secret and verified the service indeed contains the exact same value which is pasted in "plain-text", however the secret is not producing the same result as seen in the screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

```
   environment:
      bestbuy.api.url: /run/secrets/api_key
```

These lines set the value of the `bestbuy.api.url` URL to the string `/run/secrets/api_key` -- unless your application knows to check whether `bestbuy.api.url` is a file path and load the URL from there, you'll need an extra step. Docker doesn't automatically load secrets into environment variables for you, as a deliberate security decision on their part.

A Docker convention I've seen a lot is to use the `_FILE` suffix for those kinds of intermediate variables – in this case I guess `bestbuy.api.url_FILE` – and then to load secrets from that file, if specified, instead of the `bestbuy.api.url` variable.

Comment: Do you have any further information about how to get Docker to load secrets into env variables? I'm using an image that doesn't seem to support secrets via the _FILE suffix so I'll need to manually set this up myself, but your comment here is the only search result I've found that mentions "Docker doesn't automatically load secrets into environment variables for you, as a deliberate security decision on their part."

Comment: As far as I know, Docker doesn't come with anything built-in to help with this.

I think it's recommended to add this support directly in your application, if you have access to edit the code in your image, and a bit of extra time. Otherwise, I've been copy-pasting [this `file_env` shell function](https://medium.com/@adrian.gheorghe.dev/using-docker-secrets-in-your-environment-variables-7a0609659aab) (I believe originally from MySQL?) and it's been working fine.